# Array of coreGraphic gradient colors

Tags: objective-c, c, core-graphics, opengl-es-2.0

Can't create array of coreGraphic gradient colors list

I have an `if` statement for 2 types of gradients

```
CGFloat colors[8];

if (YES) {
    colors = {                               //expected expression error
        130/255.0f, 42/255.0f, 212/255.0f, 0.3,
        50/255.0f, 4/255.0f, 92/255.0f, 0.3
    };
} 
else {
    colors [] = {                             //expected expression error
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        207/255.0f, 207/255.0f, 207/255.0f, 1.0
    };
}
```

Can someone show me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign array like that. I suggest you to:

```
float col1[]={ 130/255.0f, 42/255.0f, 212/255.0f, 0.3,
        50/255.0f, 4/255.0f, 92/255.0f, 0.3};
float col2[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        207/255.0f, 207/255.0f, 207/255.0f, 1.0};
float *colors;
if (YES) colors=col1;
else colors=col2;
```